# node js mongoose how to fetch record from two collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In that below collections I want to try fetch all record from `coin_infos` collection matching `_id` of `coin_infos` with `coin_id` of `wallet_infos` and `user_id`.

coin_infos collections

```
_id:objectID(5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3),
coin_code:BTC,  
wallet_name:bitcoin,
deposite_txn_fee:3,
min_withdrawn:5,
withdrawn_txn_fee:0.001,
```

wallet_infos collections

```
 _id:objectID(5a58a4e222068e053d71220d),
 user_id:5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2,
 coin_id:5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3,
 balance:3.122858,
```

I have user ID -:5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2

output look like this:..

```
{

_id:objectID(5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3),
coin_code:BTC,
wallet_balance:3.122858,
wallet_name:bitcoin,
deposite_txn_fee:3,
min_withdrawn:5,
withdrawn_txn_fee:0.001,

"match_records" : [

_id:objectID(5a58a4e222068e053d71220d),
user_id:5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2,
coin_id:5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3,
balance:3.122858,
 ] 
}
```

My mongoDB version is **3.2.11.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$lookup` and `$match` aggregate pipeline, as you already on mongo version 3.2+

`$lookup` joins `coin_infos` collection with `wallet_infos` on `coin_id`, if match found, the wallet info will be returned as a embedded document, from the embedded documents user_id you can do `$match` and filter

```
db.coin_infos.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : "wallet_infos",
                localField : "_id",
                foreignField: "coin_id",
                as : "walletInfo"
            }
        },
        {$match : {"walletInfo.userId" : "5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2"}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: thanks for your support but in this condition localfields _id is in objectID in collection but coin_id is in string type.so is it possible to convert it

Comment: @RiyaSinghal you can convert to string by `_id.str`

Comment: db.coin_infos.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : "wallet_infos",
                localField : "_id.str",
                foreignField: "coin_id",
                as : "walletInfo"
            }
        }       
    ]
)

Comment: i am trying with this code is it right ,because it giving empty walletinfo

Comment: @RiyaSinghal any reasons for saving `ObjectId` as string

Comment: Not really ,What would be standard pattern .string or Object ID. please guide

Comment: @RiyaSinghal using same datatype for local and foreign fields is better, otherwise we need to covert one to other while joining, if same simple equality will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163087/discussion-between-riya-singhal-and-saravana).